# Jmeter how to get the dynamic parameter value in the path

Tags: http, jmeter

JMeter path contents some dynamically generated value.
 **Eg**

```
[HTTP Request]
[path-home/user?p=er3562]
```

This "p" value is dynamically generated.
I want to get this parameter value in the first HTTP request path.
This parameter value should pass through each HTTP request path.

I am new to JMeter. Please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract it somehow and convert into a JMeter Variable for later reuse. JMeter provides several [PostProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) for extracting data from different responses types, in your case the most suitable one will be [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor).

1. Add Regular Expression Extractor as a child of the request which returns that `path-home/user?p=er3562` value
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: depending on where the "interesting" value lives, the most "safe" setting is `Main sample and sub-samples`
   - Field to check: depending on where the "interesting" value comes from, in the majority of cases it's `Body` but in your case it may be i.e. `URL`
   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, it is JMeter Variable name, if JMeter finds anything it will store the result in a variable named accordingly to this field. I.e. `path-home`
   - Regular Expression: [Perl5-style](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) regular expression, in your case it would be something like: `path-home/user\?p=er(\d+)`
   - Template: if you're looking to extract a single value it will be `$1$`
3. Refer extracted value as `${path-home}` where required.

References and tips:

- You can use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination to view JMeter Variable names and test regular expressions against actual response
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](http://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [JMeter Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

Answer (score 0):

By using correlation concept ,
 regular expression extractor concept & try this key
p=er(.*?)

Comment: Can u plz explain it in more details.I did n't get it.